# Cannot login to Neo4j - AWS EC2 Marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

So I am starting up a new neo4j instance in aws ec2 using neo4j community edition from the aws marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D

The machine comes up and I set up an elastic public IP. However, when I try logging in with the default credentials neo4j/neo4j through the web neo4j browser, I get an invalid credential error.

Anyone know if the creds are different when using the marketplace ami?

Comment: I have tried:
1. Stopping neo4j service
2. Deleting auth file
3. Starting the neo4j service

Still same result. I also tried specifying the password by using the `neo4j-admin set-initial-password` command. No luck.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is kinda embarrassing. But I just realized that there is a tab labeled `usage instructions` under the ec2 instance. The text under the tab instructs me to use the instance id of the ec2 instance as the default password and that worked.